# Analyzing commit activity retrospectively in Oracle 19c

Tags: oracle, performance, database-administration

I'm trying to work out why my Oracle 19c database is "suddenly" experiencing high commit waits.  Looking in V$ACTIVE_SESSION_HISTORY and DBA_HIST_ACTIVE_SESS_HISTORY shows me that lots of sessions are waiting on "log file sync" and the blocking session is the LGWR process.  Not a sign of a problem in itself, but a couple of months ago (before a recent set of product updates) it wasn't doing that, so I'm trying to understand what has changed.  Either some code changes made over the last 2 months have caused this, or potentially the I/O system is experiencing a problem.

Because it's an OLTP system we have many different types of transaction, and I'm finding it difficult to filter out the noise from the performance views.  What I'd like to be able to do is identify the sessions which are doing most commits, and also the sessions that are doing the "largest" commits, and then I can trace these back to see which pieces of code are responsible etc.

I would therefore like to be able to create a table such as this:

| SESSION_ID | SESSION_SERIAL# | COMMIT_COUNT | COMMIT_SIZE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12345 | 3 | 132436 |

For commit size, I guessed I would need to use something like the "wait time" as an approximation and was hoping that the TM_DELTA_DB_TIME column would help me out here, but not sure how to measure the number of commits.  I had hoped that the XID column would allow me to see the transaction boundaries but it's usually NULL.

And now I've stopped to question why there isn't an easier way to do this, and whether I'm going about it the wrong way.  Surely I can't be the only person to want more in-depth understanding of the commit activity within their Oracle database.  Or am I asking for data that doesn't exist in the views?

If anybody has some tips for where to look I would be very grateful!

Comment: For live sessions you can see their total redo size (it’s a session metric) but for historic sessions and pooled sessions it’s not going to be that easy. The data is only really going to be found in mining the redo logs. It can be done reliably but it’s a bit of a slog. I recommend you make some easier measurements first - has redo rate actually increased (look at your rate of log switches).

Comment: You mention that you're querying a `DBA_HIST*` view so I assume you're licensed to use the AWR.  Assuming that's the case, what is your AWR retention period?  Could you generate an AWR report from a reasonably busy period 2 months ago and compare with an AWR report from the same period today?  The top SQL statements in both reports ought to show you pretty quickly if the problem is new code (or at least new SQL), the same code getting called much more frequently, or the same workload just taking a lot longer because of I/O subsystem waits.

Comment: @AndrewSayer thanks.  Mining V$LOG_HISTORY shows the pattern is the same before and after.  I guess this means we can conclude that the "total commit work" is the same from both periods, but this wouldn't rule out somebody "helpfully" adding a commit inside a loop, or perhaps firing statements with an autonomous transaction inside a loop.  I tried using NEXT_CHANGE# in a V$LOG_HISTORY to see if the rate of change in SCN number differs between periods.  It's currently getting through 40% less SCNs than it did in the similar period.  Not sure if that's a meaningful stat though...

Comment: @JustinCave thanks.  Our AWR retention period is a month but luckily there is a single baseline from 10 weeks ago.  I am a total novice though and not sure what to look for that I can take to the DBAs.  Under Wait Events I can see that "log file sync" is the top in both snapshots, but went from 13%->35% DB time, 5.5ms->29.44ms avg wait and total wait increased 380%. I found the "Other Instance Activity Stats" and see there's lots of redo stats here; looks like counts are down but write times are up badly.  That should be enough to take to the DBAs and storage engineers!  Thanks for help.